# How to get print preview of webpage in smartphone application

Tags: c#, c++, windows, mobile, atl

how to get an print preview content of an webpage using HTML control or web-browser control in windows mobile smart phone application using c#, c++ or ATL control.
please guide us with any technical detail or any sample application associated with it.

-Thanks in advance.
GrabIt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use Qt, you can try [this](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/01/15/capturing-web-pages/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay...

meanwhile we have a small query,

Do you believe that QT can used within Windows mobile 6.0..

Thanks.